# Automatically update database field to True with django background tasks

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, background-task

I have a Model Job that has a field `filled`. I want to automatically update `filled` to `True` if the current date and time is greater than or equal to the Job's end date and time. The end date is set when creating the job. I am using Django background task to check all Jobs in the DB and repeat the process always, but I can't get it to work. Here is my code

Model.py

```
class Job(models.Model):
    # title, description, requirements, job type etc.
    end_date = models.DateTimeField()
    current_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    filled = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

task.py

```
@background(schedule=60)
def auto_mark_as_filled(job_id):
    jobs = Job.objects.filter(pk=job_id, filled=False)
    for job in jobs:
        job.current_date = timezone.localtime(timezone.now())
        if job.current_date >= job.end_date:
            job.filled = True
            job.save()
```

I am calling the task from my forms.py. when I create a new job I register it.

forms.py

```
class CreateJobForm(forms.ModelForm):

   # class meta fields widgets etc

    def save(self, commit=True):
        job = super(CreateJobForm, self).save(commit=False)
        job.save()
        auto_mark_as_filled(job.id, repeat=60, repeat_until=None) # right here, repeat every 60seconds
        return job
```

But nothing happens when the current date is greater than or equal to the end date. I don't really know what I am doing wrong any help will be appreciated.

### UPDATE

So I found out the command `python manage.py process_tasks` needs to be run on to see if there is a new task to run after creating a new task. Manually running `python manage.py process_tasks` in the terminal every time a new task is created in production just isn't right. There has to be a way to keep that command running in te server.